# How to secure Angular 4 routes using Passport JS?

Tags: node.js, angular, google-app-engine, express, passport.js

I am planning to setup Google Sign-In using `Node JS`, `Express JS` and `Passport JS`. In that process, I have configured Google strategy using the application credentials, created a sample `.ejs` page with a sign-in button and I was able to sign-in and retrieve the user profile. Later, I have removed the sample page and tried to place all the static Angular 4 files (built using angular-cli) in the `Public` directory and wrote the following logic,

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.redirect("/home");; // Angular route
  } else {
    // require the user to log in
    // redirects to Google Sign-in page
    res.redirect("/auth/google");
  }
});
```

Now, when I start the server and visit `http://localhost:3000` , I don't see any redirection to the Google Sign-in page, instead the browser directly renders `http://localhost:3000/home`.

So, what changes should I make in order to authenticate the User and then redirect the User to the Home page. And also secure the other routes/child routes in the application ?

Answer (score 1):

## Check `if` request has a session the simple way...

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
 if(req.session){ //session exists (requesting user has a session)
   // Angular route code goes here to prevent non-authed user access
 }else{res.redirect("/");} //or res.redirect("/auth/google");
});
```

## ...or use a module like [connect-ensure-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-ensure-login#usage)

**Ensure Authentication**

```
app.get('/home',
  ensureLoggedIn('/auth/google'),
  function(req, res) {
    // Angular route code goes here to prevent non-authed user access
  });
```

If user isn't authed, the request will be redirected to `/auth/google` and the original request URL (`/home`) will be saved to the session at req.session.returnTo.